# Use mask function (for collision detection) with multiple sprites

Tags: pygame

I am brand new to Pygame and am making a game for my A-level course. I am trying to have multiple bats that I can spawn and collide with. I am using Pygames mask function for 'pixel perfect collision' but I cannot get multiple bats to spawn at the same time with the collision system also working. I tried using groups but I haven't been able to get this to work. Does anyone know how to fix my code/ a better way around this problem? Thanks! The relevant code is below...

```
class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bat1 = pygame.image.load("Sprites\Bat_enemy\Bat-1.png").convert_alpha() # For hit registration for bat
        self.bat1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.bat1, (80, 70))
        self.bat_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.bat1)
        self.bat_rect = self.bat1.get_rect()
        self.bat_x = bat_x
        self.bat_y = bat_y
    bats = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Then in main loop:

```
num_of_bats = [1]

#Bat#
for i in num_of_bats:
    bat_x = (random.randint(0, 600))
    bat_y = (random.randint(0, 600))
    bat = Bat(bat_x, bat_y, i)
    bats.add(bat) 

for bat in bats:  
    offsetP2B = (int(x - batx), int(y - self.baty)) #Player to Bat
    resultP2B = bat_mask.overlap(player_mask, offsetP2B)
```

Answer (score 1):

First get rectangle based collision working, then worry about the bitmask accuracy!

There's a couple of problems with your Sprite.  The big one is that PyGame uses `sprite.image` to draw the bitmap.  Your sprite code is using `bat1` instead.  It also needs to position the `sprite.rect` to the co-ordinate of the Bat. Furthermore, the collision mask must be called `mask`, and the sprite's collision/position `pygame.Rect` must be called `rect`.

I'm not sure if it's just a paste-o, but the sprite group definition shouldn't be inside the Sprite class.

So ... with a few minor fixups:

```
class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y, bat_image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = bat_image
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask  = pygame.mask.from_surface( self.image )
        self.rect.centre = ( bat_x, bat_y )

    def update( self ):
        # TODO: code to make this bat move/flat whatever
        pass
```

There's only minor differences here.  It's better to load the image in once, outside the sprite class, than loading it in hundreds(?) of times - once for each bat.

Now it's pretty easy to make a colony of bats:

```
import os.path

START_BAT_COUNT = 30
BAT_IMAGE_PATH  = os.path.join( 'Sprites', 'Bat_enemy', 'Bat-1.png' )

# group to hold all the bat sprites
all_bats = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Going Batty!
bat_image = pygame.image.load( BAT_IMAGE_PATH ).convert_alpha()
for i in range( START_BAT_COUNT ):
    bat_x   = (random.randint(0, 600))
    bat_y   = (random.randint(0, 600))
    new_bat = Bat( bat_x, bat_y, bat_image )
    all_bats.add( new_bat )
```

The in your main loop:

```
# move every bat
all_bats.update()

...

# paint every bat
all_bats.draw( screen )
```

Comment: Hmm, it should probably also create the `mask` outside of the sprite too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great! Being new, i've ran into another problem :/  If you want to check it out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888593/updating-multiple-items-in-a-class-not-just-one