# Updating multiple items in a class, not just one

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

In the update section of this code, only the first bat that gets made is affected by update() in class Bat()...
Outside of main loop:

```
START_BAT_COUNT = 30
BAT_IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join( 'Sprites', 'Bat_enemy', 'Bat-1.png' )

bat_image = pygame.image.load(BAT_IMAGE_PATH).convert_alpha()
bat_image = pygame.transform.scale(bat_image, (80, 70))


class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bat_health = bat_health
        self.image = bat_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect.topleft = (bat_x, bat_y)

    def update(self):
        self.bat_health -= 1 
        if self.bat_health < 0:
            new_bat.kill()

all_bats = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(START_BAT_COUNT):
    bat_x = (random.randint(0, 600))
    bat_y = (random.randint(0, 600))
    bat_health = 5

    new_bat = Bat(bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health)
    all_bats.add(new_bat)
```

Inside main loop...

```
all_bats.update()
all_bats.draw(display)
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: It's the `new_bat.kill()`.  Should be `self.kill()`.  Code inside objects is about it acting on *itself*.  If ever member-function code is referring to something defined outside the class, that's not say a constant, then something is typically wrong.

Comment: In `def update(self)` why does `self.bat_health` not give an error but `self.bat_x` gives the error `builtins.AttributeError: 'Bat' object has no attribute 'bat_x'` ? Also, thanks for the answer, it worked great!

Comment: Find where your defined `Bat.bat_x`... you didn't right?!  The variable `bat_x` only exists as the parameter to `__init__()`.  The `Bat`s `x` co-ordinate is kept in the rectangle `Bat.rect`.  You can always make a copy, for example: in `Bat.update()`, you could  use: `bat_x, bat_y = self.rect.topleft`.  if you *really* want to keep a persistent copy, make a `self.bat_x` in `__init__()`, but remember to update it and `Bat.rect` too.

Comment: In update(), `bat_x, bat_y = self.rect.topleft`   `bat_x += 5`  doesn't increase the values of `bat_x` by five, but doesn't crash the program either? But, for example, `if bat_x > 300:`   `self.kill()` does work. How come the program can read `bat_x`, but is failing to manipulate it?

Comment: `bat_x` becomes a "local variable" to that function.  So you can change it all you want, but once that function returns, it's gone.  See: https://pythonbasics.org/scope/  `self.rect` is a "member variable" of the class, so it is stored within the object.

Answer (score 0):

In [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) you must use the instance parameter (`self`) instead of an object instance in the global namespace. This means you have to call `self.kill()` instead of `new_bat.kill()`:

```py
class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.bat_health -= 1 
        if self.bat_health < 0:
            self.kill()
```